# RequestParam is always being set to a null value in spring?

Tags: spring

So, I am using the following method

```
@Override
@GET
@Path( "/stackoverflow/{question}/{answer}" )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response alwaysnull( @PathParam( "question" ) Long question,
        @PathParam( "answer" ) Long answer, @RequestParam Integer votes )
{
    
    logger.info( "Getting the question = " + question+ " and the answer = " + answer
            + "with the number of votes =" + votes );
}
```

According to all research I have done if the following request:

```
127.0.0.1:8082/stackoverflow/1/2?votes=1
```

Should log

```
Getting the question = 1 and the answer = 2 with the number of votes =1
```

However the log is currently recording

```
Getting the question = 1 and the answer = 2 with the number of votes =null
```

According to all research I have been able to do this is a simple task that should be done properly by the method I posted above.

Somehow votes is not being filled out and it is breaking my code.

Please give me some pointers on what may be going on.

Comment: You pass a param **votes** but have a variable named **status**??

Comment: I can edit that. Its called the same in the method and definition. Knew I was going to miss something

Answer (score 0):

Did you try @QueryParam instead of @RequestParam?

```java
@GET
@Path( "/stackoverflow/{question}/{answer}" )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response alwaysnull( @PathParam( "question" ) Long question,
        @PathParam( "answer" ) Long answer, @QueryParam("votes") Integer votes ){
logger.info( "Getting the question = " + question+ " and the answer = " + answer
            + "with the number of votes =" + votes );
}
```

Comment: it was a multimodule project and I had to rebuild all modules for this to work properly.  I was seeing my updated code but it wasn't being picked up properly by a previous module. Had to do a clean build and then relaunch everything for it to work properly

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is that you haven't named the parameter in the annotation.

```
@Override
@GET
@Path( "/stackoverflow/{question}/{answer}" )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response alwaysnull( @PathParam( "question" ) Long question,
        @PathParam( "answer" ) Long answer, @RequestParam( "votes" ) Integer votes )
{
    
    logger.info( "Getting the question = " + question+ " and the answer = " + answer
            + "with the number of votes =" + votes );
}
```

Comment: Standard naming conventions are to assume the name remains AFAIK.  Anyhow, it was a multimodule project and I had to rebuild all modules for this to work properly